# OnActivityResult - Not to execute code if method not complete

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I am creating a app, and in this part of the process, the user hits a submit button and it will pop up asking which email client they want to use.

Currently when I hit cancel on the popup, it will still execute the code, as in go to the next activity and show the toast message. What I would like is for it to not execute this if the user hits cancel, but if they send the email (or at least go into the email client) then execute the code.

Below are my current lines of code:

```
    public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
protected static final int EMAIL_SENT = 0;
```

My Intent to get all the email information:

```
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.subject, name));
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"),0);
}
```

Finally the onActivity:

```
        @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == EMAIL_SENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    }else{
            Intent submit = new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(submit);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
    }
    finish();
}
```

Comment: You haven't passed `EMAIL_SENT` as a request code. You must change this `startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"),EMAIL_SENT);`

Comment: I think you have misplaced the lines in the *else* block. Put it in *if* block in onActivityResult and try?

Comment: I have tried both methods. Putting the request code in does nothing. I swapped the code and put it in the if block, but now it isn't even going to the HomeActivity.class, it just goes back to the previous class (named Selection) and doesn't execute the code at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not all activities supports result back intent.
Specially if it's a known system activity.
You can do some logic in your onPause() & onResume() to check whether the data sent or not (Maybe by querying some database table of the emails).

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you just need to swap your if-else block:

```
if (requestCode == EMAIL_SENT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
{
    Intent submit = new Intent(this,HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(submit);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request Submitted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: Tried that, now it doesn't execute the code at all, as in not even working if I hit cancel button, for some reason it will only work if it's in the else block.